# c# windows form timer doesn't update properly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer, subtraction

I'm pretty new to C# and wanted to add a countdown timer to the program I'm making. The timer doesn't update after the first change unless I add `i--;` but then it starts off taking away 2 seconds instead of 1 but it works after that. I'm not sure what's going on here.

```cs
public int i = 100;

private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (i < 1)
    {
        timer1.Stop();
        StopWatch.Text = "00:00:00";
    }
    else
    {
        i--; //doesn't work without this line
        TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i);
        time = time.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        StopWatch.Text = time.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
    }
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Interval = 1000;
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer1_Tick);
    timer1.Start();
}
```

Comment: Without `i--` the `i` never changes, so you are always going to display `i-1`. With `i--` the `i` changes as needed, but because you display `i-1` instead of `i`, it first jumps two units. Remove the `time = time.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));`

Comment: @GSerg that worked thanks, I only added `time = time.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));` because `i--;` wasn't working previously, so i'm not sure why it works now.

Comment: @Jimi how would i go about adding it into the Form's constructor, I just noticed this issue

Comment: Note that you just need `i--; textBox3.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");`. -- The form constructor is the part where you find `public Form1() {  InitializeComponent(); }`, assuming that your Form is  named `Form1`. Move `timer1.Tick += Timer1_Tick;` there. Or add `timer1.Tick -= Timer1_Tick;` after `timer1.Stop();`.

Comment: @Jimi sweet that fixed the issue before it would've became a headache tomorrow, thanks for your help i appreciate it :)

Comment: No problem. Btw, I wrote `textBox3 ...`, when of course it's `i--; StopWatch.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(i).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");`. I have no idea where that other one came from. I must have pasted it in from another comment :)

Answer (score 0):

When `Timer1_Tick` first ticks `i`  is 0 and therefore if `(i < 1)` statement is true
which leads to  `timer1.Stop();`

Comment: Then it would not matter if there is `i--` in the other branch, would it?

Comment: well the else statement never called so no

Comment: But the OP says it does make a difference which is the premise of the question.

Comment: In the code of my program `i` gets changed, i'll edit it to stop confusion

Comment: @Huntard what is StopWatch, im guessing its not [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @styx it's just what i named the textbox, didn't know that existed while naming it, it's off by one capital

Comment: well the time variable will always be the same if don't do i-- because it uses the same i every iteration

Comment: @styx the problem was answered in the replies to the original comment i had to remove `time = time.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));` from the code and it works normally, thanks for taking your time to try and help me though :)